# Format Million on Excel 2007

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007, formatting

I would like to change the format predefined with Excel 2007 for million in the previous versoin I could do that but havent found a way to do this.

For example I have this:

> 1,235,000,00

and I want this:

> 1,200,000.00

Comment: Do you want to change the thousands separator from '.' to ','?  Or do you want to truncate the value 1235000 -> 1200000?

Answer (score 1):

Excel doesn't support rounding to significant digits as a number format, you have to calculate it using formulas: `ROUND`, `ROUNDUP`, and `ROUNDDOWN` mainly.

e.g. `=ROUND(A1,1-INT(LOG10(ABS(A1))))` will round A1 to 2 significant digits

e.g.2 `=ROUND(A1,A2-1-INT(LOG10(ABS(A1))))` will round A1 to A2 significant digits

Comment: but it can't use this formating for millions 1,560,500.00

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking here. I've adjusted the answer so it's more general and will round to any number of significant digits. If you are asking about commas and decimal places once you've rounded, then you just use normal cell formatting to achieve that.